# act_like_restful_authentication with authlogic v5

Tags: restful-authentication, authlogic

I am updating a really old code base to v5 from v3. The old code is using `act_like_restful_authentication` and was not transited to a new crypto.

In v5, the `act_like_restful_authentication` and its transition was removed. How can I replicate the same behavior?

I tried something like:

```
acts_as_authentic do |c|
    Authlogic::CryptoProviders::Sha1.stretches = 1
    ::REST_AUTH_SITE_KEY = ''
    c.crypto_provider = Authlogic::CryptoProviders::Sha1
  end
```

But it does not seems to be enough. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried upgrading from 3 to 4 first, before trying 5?